# How to use url to download Excel file on Internet Explorer

Tags: php, javascript, excel, internet-explorer

I have a problem when I use URL to download Excel File from my server using Internet Explorer. 
I have code below on my PHP script

```
echo "<script>
        window.location='http://localhost/complaint/export/export_complaint.xls';
    </script>";
```

This script can create automatically download action when I use Chrome as my browser, but not working in Internet Explorer. 
and I use Internet Explorer 9. 
Please advise if any suggestion for this issue. Many Thanks !

Comment: add `type="text/javascript"`attribute to `script` tag

Comment: thanks @Ander2 , it works when I download Excel 2003 format, but still failed for Excel 2007 format

Comment: @user1875301 check my answer it will work use `jQuery` for downloading files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the redirection to be done with `javascript` you can redirect with `PHP` like this:

```
header("Location: http://localhost/complaint/export/export_complaint.xls")
```

Comment: this one is simple conclusion. Thanks @Ander2

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery for this

**In jQuery:**

```
$('a#someID').attr({target: '_blank', 
                    href  : 'http://localhost/complaint/export/export_complaint.xls'});
```

Whenever that link is clicked, it will download the file in a new tab/window.

Comment: Hi Sumit, I really appreciate your suggestion. Many thanks!
but actually I'm a newbie as developer.
And I think @Ander2 answer is simple for me.